# Meteor method not returning ID to client

Tags: meteor

I am in the process of integrating stripe payments on my website, but I have run into a problem. 
I want to transition the user to a dynamic route upon submitting the payments form (iframe supplied by stripe), but the Meteor method that I call on the client returns undefined instead of the ID of the newly inserted document that I wish to transition to

Any advice?

ERROR

```
Error: Missing required parameters on path "/purchases/:purchaseId". The missing params are: ["purchaseId"]. The params object passed in was: undefined.
```

client:

```
Template.viewTab.events({
  'click #download': function(event) {
    handler.open({
      name: 'Tabr',
      description: this.title,
      amount: this.price
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  },
});

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: '..............',
  token: function(token) {
    // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`

    tabId = Tabs.findOne()._id;
    Meteor.call('makePurchase', tabId, token, function(error, purchaseId) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('makePurchaseError: ' + error);
        FlashMessages.clear();
        return FlashMessages.sendError(error.message, {
          autoHide: true,
          hideDelay: 10000
        });
      }
      console.log(purchaseId);
      Router.go('viewPurchase', purchaseId);
    });
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({

  /**
   * [makePurchase attempts to charge the customer's credit card, and if succesful
   * it inserts a new purchaes document in the database]
   *
   * @return {[String]} [purchaseId]
   */
  makePurchase: function(tabId, token) {
    check(tabId, String);
    tab = Tabs.findOne(tabId);

    Stripe.charges.create({
      amount: tab.price,
      currency: "USD",
      card: token.id
    }, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('makePurchaseError: ' + error);
        return error;
      }

      purchaseId = Purchases.insert({
        sellerId: tab.userId,
        tabId: tab._id,
        price: tab.price
      }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('InsertionError: ' + error);
          return error;
        }
        return result;
      });
    }));

    console.log(purchaseId);
    return purchaseId;
  }

});
```

Comment: Maybe try renaming it to result

Comment: what should i rename?

Comment: purchaseId in call, other than that I don't see reason why it shouldn't work, maybe try throwing error with id in error.reason ;p

Comment: To my knowledge, it doesn't matter what you name the arguments of the callback function

Comment: I think the earlier comment is correct, in the callback function of Purchases.insert() you should 'return result', not return purchaseId

Comment: didnt make a difference

Comment: Try returning result from Purchases.insert() and then return purchaseId from makePurchase (as the last line of the makePurchase method, outside of the Stripe.charges.create() function).  Right now your method itself has no return value.

Comment: @JeremyS updasted post with changes, but still doesnt work, it says that purchaseId is undefined

Comment: Ok, I think it is returning undefined because you are not receiving the callback from Stripe.charges.create() through a Future. So you need to setup a new Future() and return that from Stripe. You can look here for an example http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Async_on_server or I can post an answer with how I set up Stripe api calls if it doesn't help.